# JUnit 5 parallel test execution and singleton/static state in framework library

Tags: junit5

Actually I want to speed up my JUnit 5 tests with parallel test execution. But can't find any convenient way to avoid problems with static state in third-party frameworks: each  thread use same class loader and as result influence through common state to another test in neighbor thread.

There is small snippet of my test configuration with @Execution annotation:

```
@Execution(ExecutionMode.CONCURRENT)
class Test {

    fun logClassLoader() {
        println(SomeClass::class.java.classLoader);
    }

    @Test
    @Execution(ExecutionMode.CONCURRENT)
    fun test() {
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        logClassLoader()
    }


    @Test
    @Execution(ExecutionMode.CONCURRENT)
    fun test1() {
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        logClassLoader()
    }

}

class SomeClass
```

Seems most simplest solution to configure execution that each thread uses it's own ClassLoader with own loaded framework.
Is there any convinient for JUnit 5 way to do so?

Comment: and exactly how parallel execution would be faster than serial execution?

Comment: @Sterconium Cause of several processor cores)

Comment: I don't think you can (or it is convenient) to manually handle threading the way you mean